# remove stylesheets that was added by doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, doorkeeper

I installed doorkeeper and I don't do any configuration nor include any stylesheet of doorkeeper in my application.css, but nevertheless the doorkeeper's stylesheet is listed.

Content of application.css:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

I checke into lib/assets/stylesheets, and vendor/assets/stylesheets also not seeing any doorkeeper css. How to remove the doorkeeper css that is generated as bellow:

```
  <link href="/assets/doorkeeper/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/doorkeeper/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/assets/doorkeeper/admin/application.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I tried to read on doorkeeper's GIT page but to no avail in finding solution to my problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the Doorkeeper layouts? Check this out: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-views

Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your question, though. Also, I'm assuming the Doorkeeper CSS links are regenerating despite manual removal from the HTML.